# Show that : $ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{ \sin(n \alpha)}{n} = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that : 
$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{ \sin(n \alpha)}{n} = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2} $

(Preferably) using complex analysis tools.

Any hints or ideas is appreciated.

Comment: Uh, what's $\alpha$? Because this is unfortunately not true if, say, $\alpha = 0$. Do you want $\alpha \in (0, 2\pi)$?

Comment: Thanks for this remark, I guess for any $\alpha \neq k \pi$

Comment: (It's also false for any $\alpha \not\in (0,2\pi)$...)

Comment: Are Fourier series  good, as well?

Comment: @Avitus well, this is a problem in a Complex Analysis qualifying exam, so I think one can do it with complex analysis tools, you say all coefficients in the fourier series $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can be evaluated by contour integration by considering $$ f(z) = \frac{\pi e^{i \alpha z} e^{- i \pi z} \csc (\pi z)}{z}$$ and integrating around a square with vertices at $\pm (N+1/2) \pm (N+1/2)$ where $N$ is a positive integer (call it $C_{N})$.

Like $\pi \cot \pi z$, $\pi e^{- i \pi z} \csc(\pi z)$ has simple poles at the integers with residue $1$.

But unlike $ \displaystyle \pi \int_{C_{N}} \frac{e^{i \alpha z}  \cot(\pi z)}{z} \ dz $, the integral $\displaystyle \pi \int_{C_{N}} \frac{e^{i \alpha z} e^{- i \pi z} \csc(\pi z)}{z}\ dz$ vanishes as $N \to \infty$ if $ 0 < \alpha < 2 \pi$.

Then

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty}\pi \int_{C_{N}} \frac{e^{i \alpha z} e^{- i \pi z} \csc(\pi z)}{z}\ dz = 0 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{1} \text{Res}[f(z),n] + \text{Res}[f(z),0] + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{Res}[f(z),n]$$

$$ = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{i \alpha n}}{n} + \text{Res}[f(z),0] + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i \alpha n}}{n}$$

And since

$$ f(z) = \frac{\pi e^{i(\alpha - \pi)z} \csc (\pi z)}{z} = \pi \Big( 1 + i(\alpha - \pi)z + \mathcal{O}(z^{2}) \Big) \Big(\frac{1}{\pi z} + \mathcal{O}(1) \Big)\frac{1}{z}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{z^{2}} + i \frac{\alpha - \pi}{z} + \mathcal{O}(1) $$

we have

$$\text{Res}[f(z),0] = i(\alpha- \pi) $$

Therefore,

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{i \alpha n}}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i \alpha n}}{n} = i(\pi -\alpha)  $$

And equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation,

$$ 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (\alpha n)}{n} = \pi -\alpha $$

$$ \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (\alpha n)}{n} = \frac{\pi - \alpha}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : compute first $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\sin(k\alpha)}{n}$ by differentiating and noticing that one can recognize the real part of a geometric series.

Comment: for the convergence of the geometric series we require $|e^{i\alpha}| < 1$ which I suppose is not the case, since  $|e^{i\alpha}| = 1$. Am I right ?

Comment: The convergence doesn’t matter since you have an explicit, closed-form formula.

Answer (score 2):

Say we just want to sum that series, use,
$$ \sin(n\alpha) = \frac{e^{in\alpha} - e^{-in\alpha}}{2i}$$
Then use logarithmic series,

$$\frac1{2i} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ni\alpha}}{n} - \frac{e^{-ni\alpha}}{n} $$
Thus, we get, 
$$ \frac{1}{2i} \left\{ -\log(1-e^{i\alpha}) + \log(1-e^{-i\alpha}) \right\} $$
Now you got to simply that using identities and log rules.

Comment: I guess $$ \sin(n\alpha) = \frac{e^{in\alpha} - e^{-in\alpha}}{2i}$$ I couldn't edit because it was less than 6 characters